# dojo query for checkboxes

Tags: dojo

I want to get all my checked checkboxes from a form and i do like this(and it works)

```
var cbs = dojo.query('input:checked', 'f');
```

I wand to add another selector(class selector) to get all checked checkboxes from a form with a specified class. I tried this one but it doesn't work

```
 var cbs = dojo.query('input:checked .xClass', 'f');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this `dojo.query('input.xClass:checked', 'f');`

Pseudo-selectors like `:checked` act like filters and should be put as suffixes of other selectors. You can select checkboxes with a specified class first using `input.xClass`, then append the `:checked` as the suffix.

Comment: What does the `'f'` do in this case?  I tried google for the parameters but couldn't find anything.

Comment: (super old thread, but maybe the answer will help others)...
the 'f' is simply the id of the object to search.

The documentation only seems to be from < 1.7, then I can't find a reference of this. See section "Count of checked checkboxes in a form with id myForm"
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html

Answer (score 0):

What does the 'f' do in this case? I tried google for the parameters but couldn't find anything. –  user1477388 Oct 11 '13 at 16:20

the second parameter of the query is the starting node for the query.

For instance, the query for < input > tags begins at "#{id:inputText1}"  followed by the found nodes having the value of those found nodes, smited away with a null string.

[image]